# Check if value IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(value) != '' AND value != 0

Tags: mysql, operators

How do I check if `value IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(value) != '' AND value != 0`?

If I check a `'string' != 0` it always returns false, so its not working.

Its for a generic query that doesn't know the type of column its querying.

I need to do something like `(value IS NUMERIC TYPE AND value != 0)`

`value` could be a string, date, time, blob, number, etc.

Comment: How about a string containing '0'?

Comment: @Jack in my case a string containing 0 would be considered not empty and should return true.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps `CAST(value AS int) <> 0`?

Comment: +1  Looks like the right approach.  Although, frustratingly, the `INT` keyword isn't permitted in CAST statements.  You need `CAST(v AS SIGNED`) or similar.  (And perhaps also an `...OR CAST(v AS DECIMAL(M,N)) <> 0`, too.)

Comment: ah yeah. that signed/unsigned business always trips me up in mysql. Beats me why they couldn't have the function use the real native data type names, and actually convert to those types.

Comment: That has the same result as `'string' != 0`

Comment: @petah: true, but since OP says it's for use with unknown field types, doing `TRIM(CAST(value as varchar)) <> ''` would be equivalent.

Comment: But `TRIM(0) != ''` is true. I basically need to detect empty values. An empty value could either be `NULL`, and empty string (with white space trimmed), or 0

Answer (score 0):

Without the knowledge of column types, you could resort to regular expressions to determine whether to proceed based on stringish or numberish column data:

```
value IS NOT NULL AND 
IF(value REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$', value <> 0, TRIM(value) <> '')
```

Depending on the regular expression outcome, it will either compare against `0` or against `''`.

**Caveat** String containing `'0'` will be considered empty, but after trawling the MySQL website, I couldn't find a suitable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this before when doing SQL data migrations using recordsets.

if trim(fields(0).value & "") > "" then 'we have a value

So if it's null, it becomes an empty string, if it's not null, it becomes a trimmed string.
Most efficient method... probably not, but it works.